# Laravel event listeners in packages, where to put them?

Tags: php, email, events, laravel-4

I am writing a relatively simple Laravel 4.2 package for mail writing/sending. The component is supposed to listen for user-defined events in the main application (or another component, that is) and send on event firing.

I already created the multilanguage mail editing and event association but now I don't know where to properly put and setup my "foreach" event loop to create the actual listeners within the component.

Anyone can help me?

To better explain what I would like to do in the component:

- allow an admin to write email templates from a backend
- associate each email (or mailset) to a stated event (eg. 'user.create')
- on app execution the component loops through the saved events and register the actual listeners
- if during execution time the main application or another component fires the event, the mail component reacts by sending the corresponding emails.

Kind regards,
Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took me a bit of testing to find what I believe is a proper place for the Event::listen() loop I was referring to.

I knew I could add the listener pretty much where I wanted but for a component I had no clue. In the end I decided to build it up inside the boot() method of the ServiceProvider.

Now my component ServiceProvider does the following:

- gathers the events to listen to from the database;
- assigns a listener to each found row;
- runs a closure function in case the main application fires the associated event.

Easy enough with Laravel!